# How to recover /etc/sudoers file with vim?

Tags: data-recovery

I am trying to recover my /etc/sudoers file in my Chrome OS terminal. I can't access grub, and I don't have root access either. Possibly I need to make a new sudoers file? I already tried that, but it looks like without root access I cannot save it. I finally figured out how to kill the running processes, however now it just says the following

```
 Swap files found:
   Using specified name:
1.    .sudoers.swm
          owned by: root   dated: Tue Sep 29 22:45:22 2015
         [cannot be opened]
2.    .sudoers.swn
          owned by: root   dated: Tue Sep 29 15:39:12 2015
         [cannot be opened]
3.    .sudoers.swo
          owned by: root   dated: Tue Sep 29 15:26:39 2015
         [cannot be opened]
4.    .sudoers.swp
          owned by: root   dated: Mon Sep 28 19:06:17 2015
         [cannot be opened]
   In directory ~/tmp:
      -- none --
   In directory /var/tmp:
      -- none --
   In directory /tmp:
      -- none --

Enter number of swap file to use (0 to quit):
```

Comment: That question doesn't have an answer, plus the issue is different (file locked by running process vs. permissions issue)

Answer (score 0):

If you break `sudo` configuration and you don't have root access, there is really no cure. This is by design - if there was a way to reconfigure `sudo` without being root, then having `sudo` makes no sense in the first place.

Unless you find a way to get root access, you will have to [reinstall the system](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en).

Comment: You can boot your system with a live cd and fix the sudoers file. I would try that before reinstalling.

Comment: @chaos Actually I already tried booting my system with a live CD, but I have a bad feeling that either grub isn't on here or the time is set to 0, which I can't fix without sudo. How would I reinstall it? apt-get doesn't work on my computer. ):

Comment: @ElsieReynolds I have added a link to chromebook recovery procedure to the answer.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I tried doing that, but an 'unexpected error has occured' I tried using a different live CD, but it didn't work. What should I do now?

Comment: @ElsieReynolds maybe you should contact Chromebook support, as Google suggests? You can also take out the HDD and fix it on another computer, though I'm not sure if you're comfortable with taking computers apart.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I think I'll contact chromebook support first. Thanks for the help. (: